# Is it possible to merge WordPress CSS hosted on CDN? Better solution?

Tags: wordpress, minify

we're tryng to merge CDN hosted CSS files in order to increase Google PageSpeed results. IS it possible? What is the fastest solution?

1. Having multiple minified files hosted on CDN
2. Having one minified self-hosted files locally?

What's your best approach to this problem?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just to improve the Google Pagespeed result you should identify the CSS code necessary to render the above the fold content and then inline it in the head section. Like explained in this article: https://www.storyblok.com/tp/how-to-get-pagespeed-100

A CDN is always good for static files but Google Pagespeed doesn't measure if your CSS is served by a CDN. Instead it measures if the CSS is blocking the rendering of your page.

If you have multiple CSS files try to merge them. Inline the CSS for the above the fold content and insert following link tag to load the rest of the styles after the page has rendered:

```
<link rel="preload" id="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/below.css" as="style" onload="this.rel='stylesheet'">
<noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/below.css"></noscript>
```

The rel=preload needs a polyfill to work with older browsers. So be sure to include following script also:

```
<script>
/*! loadCSS. [c]2017 Filament Group, Inc. MIT License */
!function(a){"use strict";var b=function(b,c,d){function e(a){return h.body?a():void setTimeout(function(){e(a)})}function f(){i.addEventListener&&i.removeEventListener("load",f),i.media=d||"all"}var g,h=a.document,i=h.createElement("link");if(c)g=c;else{var j=(h.body||h.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]).childNodes;g=j[j.length-1]}var k=h.styleSheets;i.rel="stylesheet",i.href=b,i.media="only x",e(function(){g.parentNode.insertBefore(i,c?g:g.nextSibling)});var l=function(a){for(var b=i.href,c=k.length;c--;)if(k[c].href===b)return a();setTimeout(function(){l(a)})};return i.addEventListener&&i.addEventListener("load",f),i.onloadcssdefined=l,l(f),i};"undefined"!=typeof exports?exports.loadCSS=b:a.loadCSS=b}("undefined"!=typeof global?global:this);

/*! loadCSS rel=preload polyfill. [c]2017 Filament Group, Inc. MIT License */
!function(a){if(a.loadCSS){var b=loadCSS.relpreload={};if(b.support=function(){try{return a.document.createElement("link").relList.supports("preload")}catch(b){return!1}},b.poly=function(){for(var b=a.document.getElementsByTagName("link"),c=0;c<b.length;c++){var d=b[c];"preload"===d.rel&&"style"===d.getAttribute("as")&&(a.loadCSS(d.href,d,d.getAttribute("media")),d.rel=null)}},!b.support()){b.poly();var c=a.setInterval(b.poly,300);a.addEventListener&&a.addEventListener("load",function(){b.poly(),a.clearInterval(c)}),a.attachEvent&&a.attachEvent("onload",function(){a.clearInterval(c)})}}}(this);
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you Alexander, what does rel=preload exactly do?

Comment: It helps the browser to load the assets asynchronous. With a modern browser this will improve the "time to interaction" about 10 % https://www.w3.org/TR/2015/WD-preload-20150721/